# WP8.1 Live Tile with badge

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I've two questions regarding TileSquare71x71IconWithBadge/TileSquare150x150IconWithBadge/TileWide310x150IconWithBadgeAndText templates.

1. Why do I have to set "image" attribute? I provided all the logos (in visual assets in package manifest), why doesn't the app just grab the icons from there?
2. Where can I find logo templates for those tiles? I can't seem to get it to look right using regular app logos.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update the tile to set a badge. If you want the default tile plus a badge then you can just update the badge and leave the tile alone.

The *IconWithBadge tiles allow for custom icons, which is why you need to set the image. You won't necessarily use the app's default icon. For example, the Phone app changes its icon from a phone to a phone with a tape to indicate the presence of voice mail messages.

You can find descriptions of the templates and example XML in the [tile template catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761491.aspx). Also see [Details on sizing, padding, scaling, and transparency for Windows Phone Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781198.aspx#details_on_sizing__padding__scaling__and_transparency_for_windows_phone_store_apps)

Comment: I think I have to update the tiles at least once, to enable *IconWithBadge templates, don't I?

I still can't seem to find icons for said templates. Whenever I use regular ones, either logo is too small or space between logo and a number is too wide.